# How to typecast a void pointer to an int pointer and then store an int in it?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
1.    void* x;
2.    x = new int [10];
3.    x = static_cast<int*>(x);
4.    *x = 2;
```

On line 4, I am getting:  `error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type`

Comment: **don't** fiddle with `void*` in C++! This is notoriously error prone and liable to violate the strict aliasing rules (and thus envoke undefined behaviour).

Comment: C++ is statically typed. That means the type of `x` is determined as compile time. Its value may change at runtime, but it remains a `void*` forever - even if you assign an `int*`. That's why you have type conversions in assignments, precisely because you can't change the type of the target to match the source.

Comment: @Walter As far as I remember, there should be exceptions for void* and char* types in strict aliasing rules. Otherwise things like memset could not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the new pointer type.

You static casted x, but the type information is lost after the static cast since at declaration time x is void*.

x will persist to be void* throughout his lifetime.

Here's a working code sample :

```
     void* x;
     int* ptr;
     x = new int[10];
     ptr = static_cast<int*>(x);
     *ptr = 2;
```

OR alternativelly, you can asign and cast in the same line :

```
    *(static_cast<int*>(x)) = 2;
```

Comment: I think this violates the strict aliasing rules and hence envokes UB.

Comment: @Walter Yes and no. NO because the type pointed at by the pointer is int and has sizeof(int), and when allocated and written to is refered by int type. So this exact code snippet is ok . YES because this sort of coding is very easy to get you to aliasing rule violation (basically using void* to keep pointers is similar to reintrepret casting all over the place)...

Comment: @Walter: There's no aliasing; this is an `int*` pointer pointing to an array of `int`. Shenanigans like this can easily lead to aliasing violations since there's no type-checking, but there's none here since the types are correct despite not being checked.

Comment: @Walter I don't think so. Because you cannot dereference a pointer value of type `void*`. Strict aliasing seems to apply only to dereferenceable pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

Since any pointer (except pointer to member and pointer to functions, which are something else entirely) can be implicitly converted to a void pointer, your line 2 implicitly converts the result of `new int[10]` from `int *` to `void *`.

Similarly, your line 3 explicitly converts `x` to `int *` (the `static_cast`) and the result of that is implicitly converted back and stored in `x`.   That has no net effect.   If the compiler is smart enough, it would ignore that statement completely.

What you need to do is introduce another variable which is a pointer to `int`.

```
void *x;
x = new int[10];
int *y = static_cast<int *>(x);
*y = 2;
```

If you really want to use a void pointer without any variable that is an int pointer, do this;

```
void *x;
x = new int[10];
*(static_cast<int *>(x)) = 2;
```

That is exceedingly ugly, and only needed in specialised circumstances.

In practice, unless you need the void pointer for something else in particular, eliminate it completely.

```
int *x;
x = new int[10];
*x = 2;
```

The fact that there is no need to monkey around with any explicit type conversions makes this less error prone too.

Comment: I think this violates the strict aliasing rules and hence envokes UB.

Comment: You think wrong.   The only dereferencing is of an int * (implicitly or explicitly) to access elements of a dynamically allocated array of int.   There is no type punning going on.